# Decelerating delegate method of the scrollView is not called for vertical scrolling?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

The scrollView delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView` is not get called for vertical scrolling(It is working well for horizontal scrolling) I don't know how to make it inform the View controller about the deceleration of vertical scrolling. help me to know if it is possible?

```
Edit:-I've enabled paging in the scrollView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but I just verified that it does in fact get sent - run [this project from github](https://github.com/dhoerl/ScrollWatcher). I verified the message comes with both directionLock on and off.

Comment: Great - I enabled paging in the above project and I still get that message, in both vertical and horizontal directions, flicking the view. I suggest you get it, then see if you can find the right set of options to duplicate your situation. I just cannot make the message not appear.